# Thread process only the last value

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, multithreading

I am new to VB.net threading, I have created an application that creates a thread to check if persons name and age comming from a serial port are coreclty stored in Access-DB.

this is a part of the code

```
Public Class MainForm
...
Public accessDBThr As Thread
.. .
Public Class CParameters
    Public p1 As String
    Public p2 As String
End Class
...

Private para As CParameters
...
```

The searchThrd is created in port dataReceived event handeler

```
searchThrd= New Thread(AddressOf isFoundinAccessDB)
                    para.p1 = name
                    para.p2 = age
                    searchThrd.Start(para)
```

This searchThrd executes isFoundinAccessDB to search for the data in the Access DB.

```
Public Sub isFoundinAccessDB(ByVal param As Object)
    ' should wait 5 seconds for the data to be saved in the Access DB, then 
    ' start search for the data in the DB
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 5)  
    para = CType(param, CParameters)
    Dim name As String = para.p1
    Dim age As String = para.p2

    Try
        If database.DataSearch(name, age) Then
            msgbox("Found")
        Else
            msgbox("Not found")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        mesgbox(ex.message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The problem is, when receiving several data from serial port within 5 seconds  the method **isFoundinAccessDB()** 
(because of thread.sleep(1000 * 5)) is always searching for the last data and ignores the first recieved data

For example  if the port recieved ("x1,20", "x2,22", "x3,23", "x4,65") as data, the mehtod isFoundinAccessDB() always search for the last data ("x4,65")

How can this problem be fixed and search for the up-to-date values?

Comment: Problem seems to be in `database.DataSearch(name, age)` method. It could be returning only the last items.

Comment: the method isFoundinAccessDB receives the actual data then sleeps for 5 seconds, after that it calls database.DataSearch(name, age) which searchs for the data with the last values, why age and name have the last values although they are in separated thread and defined by DIm not as static

Comment: I'd suggest to manipulate data through serial port in a better way, either by ReceivedBytesThreshold property or by identifying any separator or EoF in the incoming data, so to process each string separately. Would you please post the serialport management sub?

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli there is no problem to send data coming from the serial port separately. The problem is, when receiving data, the thread calls the method directly using the new data as parameter, this function has local variables name and age, which should have the actual data. But because of the sleep function, the always takes the last data as an input parameter.  This problem i have solved by movin the sleep function inside database.DataSearch(name, age), but i dont know why the variables name and age have the same values in the different calls.

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually create the threads and execute them?  It sounds like an issue with the variable capture.